# Resolver Mapping Template development guidelines

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, vtl

**Subject**
I'm using amplify with GraphQL and DynamoDB as backend which works through AppSync. AppSync generates json based on vtl and executes it (I don't know in fact what part of the service executes it) - so it names as [Resolver Mapping Template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-changelog.html)

I need to cover all my GraphQL endpoints with custom resolvers written by me but development hurts, cause I cannot find any workaround how to simplify development and testing except via aws console, what is slow and inconvenient

**What I tried**
As an approach I tried to create `DynamoDB` json files and upload them via `awscli`, but `AppSync` uses another json format - `Resolver Mapping Template`

**What I need**
I would like to know any workaround and guidelines how to develop, debug and test my resolvers.
So I need 2 options or both

1. Compare generated template with all `$util` stuff. nice to have
2. Execute generated template via cli into DynamoDB for checking results (or maybe there are any mock system). great to have

Comment: Are you sure you need custom resolver for ALL endpoints, and auto generated ones don't meet your need? Also if you really need a custom resolver, follow https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#add-a-custom-resolver-that-targets-a-dynamodb-table-from-model so that we can version control your resolver vtl code, and not just via aws console

Comment: @ model creates different tables for every type annotated with it. I'm not experienced user of DynamoDB, but after reading and watching specs and tutorials I got that needs to build it via partitions, sk and GSI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k
I still staying between two options - use @ model which produce the structure I don't like to much or use resolvers what is not convenient to develop. But I like second option more for flexibility

Comment: > follow aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/…
thank you, I'm doing similar to it, problem that for every `vtl` change I need to push it(5min+) or write and debug through aws console

Comment: Well, the video shows "Advanced" usage while for most cases the auto generated code are decent enough for use. So I lean towards option 1.

Comment: Thank you @YikSanChan, I will follow your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation would be to use the Amplify CLI to manage auto-creating the resolvers as well as updating them yourself to alleviate some of the 'development hurts' part.

I noticed that you mentioned one of the things you are looking for is the ability to rapidly test the resolvers (that in this case amplify cli will create for you) but as stated it will take some time with every amplify push for the cfn to update. What might interest in you (and potentially alleviate this issue for you) is this new RFC for the amplify cli: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1433

See if it covers your needs if not, add a comment to that github post.

Comment: This RFC is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!